# Creating a by letter effect with visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, command, prompt

I would like to create an effect in visual studio where text shows up on the screen not all at once, but letter by letter with a certain amount of time between each letter appearing. I plan to open a different module that will have this code in it from my main module. Any ideas? Here is my coding so far. I am making a command prompt.

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim line As String
    Console.Title = "Command"
    Console.WriteLine("Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]")
    Console.WriteLine("<c> 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All right reserved.")
    Console.WriteLine(" ")
    Do
        Console.Write("C:\Users\Bob>")
        Line = Console.ReadLine()
        If line = "help" Then
            Console.WriteLine("hello world")
            Console.WriteLine(" ")
        ElseIf line = "help1" Then
            Console.WriteLine("hello again, world!")
            Console.WriteLine(" ")
        ElseIf line = "exit" Then
            Environment.Exit(0)
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Command not found.")
            Console.WriteLine(" ")
        End If
    Loop While line IsNot Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace all of your `Console.WriteLine` with `Marquee("Text here")`

**Update**: As Walt points out in the comments it should be noted this approach will lock up the application until the text has finished displaying. If this is not desired then you should think about offloading it to another thread or creating a timer event.

```
     Sub Main()

            Marquee("Hello World")
            Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

    Sub Marquee(StringToWrite As String)

        For i As Integer = 0 To StringToWrite.Length - 1
            Console.Write(StringToWrite.Substring(i, 1))
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
        Next



    End Sub
```

Comment: The answer will work, but realized that you are stalling the main application thread while updating the text.

Comment: @WaltRitscher correct, I don't think it's a problem in this situation though as the UI should be locked until the text on screen has been fully displayed. We could offload it to another thread or hook up a timer event but again I don't feel it's required or in the scope of the question. It's absolutely worth pointing out this will lock the app though. I've updated my answer to include this caveat.

Answer (score 0):

For a windows form app, my best shot is this:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim M As Integer = 1
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Dim T As String = "" + TextBox1.Text
        Label1.Text = Label1.Text + Mid(T, M, 1)
        M = M + 1
    End Sub
    'You can use any trigger here
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End Sub
End Class
```